# grok parsing issue

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have an input line that looks like this:

`localhost_9999.kafka.server:type=SessionExpireListener,name=ZooKeeperSyncConnectsPerSec.OneMinuteRate`

and I can use this pattern to parse it:

`%{DATA:kafka_node}:type=%{DATA:kafka_metric_type},name=%{JAVACLASS:kafka_metric_name}`

which gives me this:

```
{
  "kafka_node": [
    [
      "localhost_9999.kafka.server"
    ]
  ],
  "kafka_metric_type": [
    [
      "SessionExpireListener"
    ]
  ],
  "kafka_metric_name": [
    [
      "ZooKeeperSyncConnectsPerSec.OneMinuteRate"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to split the `OneMinuteRate` into a seperate field but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried this:

`%{DATA:kafka_node}:type=%{DATA:kafka_metric_type},name=%{WORD:kafka_metric_name}.%{WORD:attr_type}"`

but get nothing back then.

I'm also using https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to test these out...

Comment: Actually, I got the `OneMinuteRate` field with your last regex. Escape the dot, btw. If it still does not work, try `name=%{DATA:kafka_metric_name}\.%{GREEDYDATA:attr_type}` at the end

Comment: I missed deleting the `"` at the end too...blah

Comment: Also, do I need to escape the `.`? It seems to be working without it

Comment: Yes, if you only expect a literal dot there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use your last regex with an escaped `.` (note that a `.` matches any char but newline and a `\.` will match a literal dot char), or use `DATA` type for the last but one field and a `GREEDYDATA` for the last field:

```
%{DATA:kafka_node}:type=%{DATA:kafka_metric_type},name=% {DATA:kafka_metric_name}\.%{GREEDYDATA:attr_type}
```

Since `%{DATA:name}` translates to `(?<name>.*?)` and `%{GREEDYDATA:name}` translates to `(?<name>.*)`, the `name` part will match any chars, 0 or more occurrences, as *few* as possible, up to the first `.`, and `attr_type` `.*` pattern will greedily "eat up" the rest of the line up to its end.